# How to insert a persistent div without obscuring content in a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension where a content script, written in React (with TypeScript), inserts a div at the bottom of the window. This div spans the entire width of the window and is intended to serve as a persistent notification bar. However, I'm encountering an issue where the div obscures content on various websites, despite trying several methods to prevent this.

I'm looking for a way to ensure this div is always visible and doesn't interfere with the page's content, no matter the site. Here's a simplified version of my current code:

```
const MyNotificationDiv = () => (
  <div style={{position: 'fixed', bottom: 0, left: 0, width: '100%', zIndex: '1000'}}>
    {/* Content */}
  </div>
);

export default MyNotificationDiv;
```

I'd greatly appreciate any advice on how to make this div coexist peacefully with all types of web content or if there's a better approach to displaying a persistent bar in a Chrome extension.

Thank you in advance!

Here are the approaches I've attempted:

- Using position: `fixed` with `z-index`: I've tried fixing the div to the bottom of the window and adjusting the z-index, but it still overlaps with some page elements.
- Adding `margin-bottom` or `padding-bottom` to the body: I've attempted to push the content up, but the dynamic nature of some sites makes this unreliable.
- Inserting the `div` at the top of the page: I've also tried placing the div at the top, but this hasn't resolved the issue either.

Comment: `but it still overlaps with some page elements.` of course it does, only pages less than viewport height won't have your addition obscuring part of them. What did you expect your div to do? be visible and invisible at the same time?

Comment: As above its confusing what you want the ideal outcome to be. How could any element be overlayed on a page and not...well...overlay the page? Your possible approaches sort of hint at what might be your acceptable solution -- like pushing the content up instead of overlaying it. Doing that at the CSS level isn't doable in a reliable way cross-site.  Youd usually solve this problem by overlauing but making the div closeable, or providing the functionality instead in the extension popover.

Comment: Wouldn't using chrome.notifications API serve your requirement? It doesn't add a separate notification bar on each tab though, in case that's what you need

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you want your injected element to behave differently depending on the current scroll position? For example - overlap the site's elements until the user reaches the bottom of the page, and attain `position:fixed;bottom:0` if the user has scrolled to the bottom of the page?

Comment: Thanks guys for your reply. This is the current behavior of the div "chrome extension interface":
[![what-i-dont-want.png](https://i.postimg.cc/VLbngYmQ/what-i-dont-want.png)](https://postimg.cc/1fs8518J)

And this is what I'd like to do:
[![what-i-want.png](https://i.postimg.cc/g2p9k20G/what-i-want.png)](https://postimg.cc/nC3S3Z7W)

Of course, if this is not possible, I'll find another way to display the UI of my extension. Thanks a lot for your reply. I'm a beginner and your help is very appreciated!